# flutter bottomsheet Click intercepted

Tags: flutter

I got a requirement. When entering the record page, the `calculator keyboard` needs to pop up automatically. If the user clicks the close button at this time, the page should be closed directly.

I use the `modal_bottom_sheet` package, but when I click the close button in the upper left corner, the button is not pressed, but first the calculator `keyboard` moves out of the screen, and then I click the `close button` again, the current page will close.

How can I not block the click event when the `bottom sheet` pops up, that is, I want to click the close button, move out of the calculator keyboard at the same time, and respond to the close button (including other widgets).

[image]

Comment: Please share some code how you have tried it.